# ftpd.service failed to load: No such file or directory

Tags: ftp, inetd

```
$ sudo apt-get install ftpd
Reading package lists... Done                         
Building dependency tree                              
Reading state information... Done                                                                                                                                                                         
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:                                                                                                                           
  ax25-node libax25 linux-headers-3.19.0-15 linux-headers-3.19.0-15-generic linux-image-3.19.0-15-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-15-generic linux-signed-image-3.19.0-15-generic                        
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.                                                                                                                                                                  
The following NEW packages will be installed:                                                                                                                                                             
  ftpd                                                                                                                                                                                                    
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.                                                                                                                                            
Need to get 0 B/48.9 kB of archives.                                                                                                                                                                      
After this operation, 146 kB of additional disk space will be used.                                                                                                                                       
Selecting previously unselected package ftpd.                                                                                                                                                             
(Reading database ... 359757 files and directories currently installed.)                                                                                                                                  
Preparing to unpack .../ftpd_0.17-34_amd64.deb ...                                                                                                                                                        
Unpacking ftpd (0.17-34) ...                                                                                                                                                                              
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...                                                                                                                                                            
Setting up ftpd (0.17-34) ...
```

Now Run it

```
$ sudo service ftpd start
Failed to start ftpd.service: Unit ftpd.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to

```
/etc/init.d/openbsd-inetd start
```

Since ftpd is part of [inetd](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/inetd).

Comment: Even doing that doesn't seem to open port 21, the default FTP port

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get `ftpd` to work, even after launching the confusingly named `openbsd-inetd` service, so I just switched to `pure-ftpd` which seemed to launch right away and listen to port 21. The goal of `inetd` seemed to be to simplify things but that was not my experience.